# how to include Allegro5 into a project for the first time?

Tags: allegro, allegro5

hi i am trying to download allegro, as stated in the title, i am using [this guys](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y13-ZwTR-lE) youtube video for help and it has been more helpful than i thought it'd be, but of course i run into some sort of error. in the video, he tells you to go into the property pages -> configuration properties -> linker -> input -> additional dependencies and then type in "allegro-5.0.1-monolith-md-debug.lib". this is where i am getting my error, the compier is telling me that it can't open the file(error: LNK1104, i thought that it might have something to do with the versions being different, considering it is a few years old atm. i looked online and i tried going to common properties -> references -> add new reference, but it was blank. i tried including allegro by adding it to the "include libraries" and "library directories" in the VC++ Directories page but that doesnt work either. im totally lost. did i type in the wrong thing? im using visual studio 2013 and it seems like allegro.cc says the 2013 version isnt supported or something? i dont know...

Answer (score 0):

OK, it seems you are lost with this, perhaps the youtube video uses an old version of allegro and when you try to add the file `allegro-5.0.1-monolith-md-debug.lib` it refers to the one from version **5.0.1**, however, allegro currently is at version **5.0.10**, and that is the one you probably have downloaded.

Try changing the version number in the file to see if it compiles and don`t worry, vs2013 is compatible with this (I am currently using that one :))

By the way, you should be familiar with *lib files and the workflow in visual studio before embarking in the wonderful journey it is to develop a game, it will ease everything later on **trust me**.

P.D.: The video seems to explain the things nicely, however I recommend you to follow it from [this page insteas of only the youtube channel](http://fixbyproximity.com/2d-game-development-course/). Why? I learned to use allegro5 with it.

Also, [the wiki](http://wiki.allegro.cc/index.php?title=Windows,_Visual_Studio_2010_and_Allegro_5) has information about installing allegro on Windows, if you want to have a look there.

Good Luck!